# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage' "?

Tags: python, azure

I am quite beginner in python. I am using Spyder (Python 3.6) (Anaconda distribution). I am trying to access the azure blob storage from python script. I have installed Azure environment using Anaconda Navigator. I am importing BlockBlobService from azure.storage.blob. However, I am getting error **ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'azure.storage'**. 
Is there something missing in order to access the azure blob storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for summary, your issue is resulted from the conflict between python 2.7 version you installed and the python version with Anaconda.

The packages you installed should to be in the python 2.7 environment. However, spyder uses the Anaconda self-brought python environment.

Command line uses system python environment which is determined by the the previous python environment variable in the path.